# I want to remove all the German stop words from data set

Tags: python

I want to remove the german stop words from my data set before fitting my model and predicting accuracy. I am not sure why the below code is not able to help. All NLTK and associated libraries have already been installed.

```
import nltk
nltk.download()

from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
stemmer = SnowballStemmer('german', ignore_stopwords=True)


class StemmedCountVectorizer(CountVectorizer):

        def build_analyzer(self):
        analyzer = super(StemmedCountVectorizer, self).build_analyzer()
        return lambda doc: [stemmer.stem(w) for w in analyzer(doc)]


stemmed_count_vect = StemmedCountVectorizer(stop_words='german')

text_mnb_stemmed = Pipeline([('vect', stemmed_count_vect), ('tfidf',
                            TfidfTransformer()), ('mnb',
                            MultinomialNB(fit_prior=False))])

text_mnb_stemmed = text_mnb_stemmed.fit(X, y)

predicted_mnb_stemmed = text_mnb_stemmed.predict(X)

np.mean(predicted_mnb_stemmed == y)
```

Comment: Not for the OP, but for other readers wondering what are stop words (I didn't know that either) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words

Answer (score 18, accepted):

if you want to just remove german stop word from doc , than you can just pass stopword list in CountVectorizer function

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer


german_stop_words = stopwords.words('german')

vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words = german_stop_words) # Now use this in your pipeline
```

i am not sure whether your concern is about removing german dataset from your respective column or while vectorizing you want german stopword to be excluded.

CountVectorizer is not used for removing Stopword from respective column, it is used for vectorizing your corpus

if you just  want to remove stopword from column from your dataframe, you can simply do this...

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['how are you. vom und viel','hope this help aber','alle'], columns = ['x']) 


def stop_word_removal(x):
    token = x.split()
    return ' '.join([w for w in token if not w in german_stop_words])


 df['removed_stop_word']  = df['x'].apply(stop_word_removal)

     x                           removed_stop_word
 0   how are you. vom und viel   how are you.
 1   hope this help aber         hope this help
 2   alle
```

Comment: but if I want to remove the stop word from just two of my cols from my data set then in that case what would be the solution? let's say that I have two cols x and y from where i want to remove the stop words in my dataframe df

Comment: While vectorizing I want to remove the german stop words, if you see my code there is nothing wrong but the code runs forever. at the first instance, it asked me to install all the libraries and when I did that still no success. but your code seems to work fine..Thank you so much!!